How can I resolve this error in apache tomcat 9.0.98
localhost:8086/App1/fs

HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

TYPE Status Report

Message The requested resource [/App1/fs] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.98

I tried every possible thing to resolve this error such

Verified servlet mapping in FirstServlet.java

Verified context path in web.xml

Cleaned and rebuilt project

Checked Tomcat logs for errors or exceptions


XML FILE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">

  <display-name>App1</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>

    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>

    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>

    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>

    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>

FirstServlet.java
package pack1;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;


@WebServlet("/fs")

public class FirstServlet extends GenericServlet 
{

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {

        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();

        res.setContentType("text/html");
        

        String name=req.getParameter("uname");

        String e_mail=req.getParameter("umail");
        

        pw.println("<center>");

        pw.println("***********Data From Html***********");

        pw.println("<br> UserName is : "+name);

        pw.println("<br> Mail_id is : "+e_mail);

        pw.println("</center>");

    }

}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<title>Index Page</title>

</head>

<body>

    <center>

        <form action="fs" method="post">

            UserName : <input type="text" name="uname"/> <br><br>

            Mail_id : <input type="text" name="umail"/> <br><br>

         <input type="submit" value="Send the data To Servlet"> 

        </form>

    </center>

</body>

</html>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How do you deploy your application to tomcat?
